# Glassfish logs on JSF Page

Tags: java, ajax, logging, glassfish, richfaces

I have JSF with Richfaces app on Glassfish server. Is it possible to make an ajax window on the page and show info from Glassfish's log file that is located in [GlassfishFolder]/domains/domain1/logs/server.log? And also I want to clean up that log to make it look like in NetBeans.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

Create a commandLink

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{Bean.method}" reRender="output" />
```

Create output to view server.log contents

```
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{Bean.logcontent}" />
```

Bean.method pulls the contents of server.log ([see java file io](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)) and stores it in the logcontent variable.  When output is re-rendered it will display the server.log file.

You can manipulate logcontent in your Bean to make the output look however you wish.